# Javascript Add number without split

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

My first question was not really clear, sorry about that. So, I know about "split" method in JavaScript and now I want to add number to random array on a position that I can choose inside array, but without "split". Question is for understanding how algorithm "inside" "split" method is working.
I wrote random array, so my idea is to use loop second times for a random array, create empty array add that number to position, then number that was before the position of our new number add to empty array and then got confused a bit.

```
var array1 = [];
for (var k= 0, t=100; k<t; k++){
    array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 300))
};

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: _I need to add number (...) to position that i'm choosing_... I don't see that. With this code you just generate an array of random numbers. How are you adding the number to the position (the one you're choosing)?

Comment: your question and the respective code is confusing

Comment: You can always use a loop and move everything manually. What have you tried to far? Why don't you want to use `split` (`splice`)? Or is this homework...?

Comment: By saying `Is any algorithm without "split"?` do you mean you want to use other methods or do you want to write the method yourself?

Comment: Voting to close as the question you're asking is unclear. Please rephrase your question then edit your post.

Comment: @lealceldeiro My guess is he's helpfully giving us code that creates a random array so when we give him the solution, we don't also need to write that first...

Comment: I know algorithm with split method. But i'm interested how to do this without ready methods.

Comment: @rollback you should add that to you question: `I'm interested in how to do this without any JavaScript built in functions`. Because, for instance, there is an answer provided that does exactly that, uses a built in function.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your code has to do with the question, but you can use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to add an element at a specified index

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
arr.splice(1, 0, 'bam');
//         ^ index
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ... it was faster to answer than to find the duplicate; now it's closed for good @Ivan

Comment: @bambam I found the duplicate by looking at OP's earlier questions :) I bet this is homework.

Comment: @bambam look at the comment posted by the OP (`I know algorithm with split method. But i'm interested how to do this without ready methods`). This might not be what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Agree with you @bambam. I'm just pointing that out, since the OP is (persistently) asking about something else, not `splice` or any other built in function. Of course I would use what's already implemented (like `splice`).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not informative question, split method i know very well, but inside, i think, split method contains algorithm. So that was my question, how to add/delete elements from array without "split"

Comment: @lealceldeiro :-) As soon as they manage to write a clear, good question, I'm sure someone takes the time to write an answer with a more specialised solution.

Comment: There you go, no `split` used in the answer @rollback